# System.IO.Directory.Exists() use with both Windows and Linux

Tags: c#, mono

I am working on a C# console app that needs to be able to run on both Windows and Linux.  It will run on .NET 3.5 and Mono.  I would like to be able to check to see if a directory exists inside of the currently running directory.  Since Windows uses a backslash for directory traversal, and Linux uses a forward slash, how do I check to see if a directory exists within another directory?

I am using System.IO.Directory.Exists.  I think a simple way to do this is to first check the current working folder for either "/" or "\" to determine which one to use, however in some instances there may be an escape character which would mess things up!

Comment: Mono provides a portability guide, have a look at the Path Separators section : http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines:Application_Portability

Comment: That's a great link.  Thanks for that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows is quite tolerant about this. You can use the forward slash and it will understand.

If you don't want to take the chance it might get confused (I'm not 100% sure Windows *always* understands this), you can use [`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Use `Path.Combine` to build your paths. Consider this code:

```
var path = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
    "childFolder");
```